# Creating multiple circles in D3 with array lists

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jscript

I am new to D3. I have been trying to display multiple circles for a list of arrays. However, I have managed to obtain a circle but it displays only the last record's circle. Below is the code. Can anyone help me to create three different circles?

```
var xyz = [[320, 52, 900], [220, 47, 1233], [89.5, 287, 899], [424.5, 
93.5, 1250]];
var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
              .data(xyz)
              .enter()
              .append("circle");
circles.attr("cx", d=>d[0])
            .attr("cy", d=>d[1])
            .attr("r", d=>d[2]/80);
```

How to loop this on D3?

Comment: Seems to be work. What's the issue? https://jsbin.com/julabep/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: "`svg.selectAll("foo")`" it's cleaner to do `svg.selectAll(null)` when you want to ensure all data is put into enter selection

Comment: last item has biggest `x` coord -- perhaps you have wrongly defined `viewBox` (if svg var refers to svg tag) or `transform` (if svg var refers to g tag) attributes above